# Ajax and JS files

Tags: javascript, ajax, file

I am having a problem on ajax calls. Each time I want to refresh or add more data in an ajax controlled area, I have to include some js files.

this is my usual script for submiting data

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ajax_loader_order(x, y) {
        $.getScript("js/plugins.js");
        $.getScript("js/scripts.js");
        req = $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "products.php?order=" + y + "&orderud=" + x,
            datatype: "html",
            success: function(data){
                $('#container').html(data);
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#main").offset().top}, 1000);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
```

Loading those js files each time, makes the website heavier and slower.

Is there a way with which I can load those js files on first load and every time I call this ajax function, to be included?

Thank you in advance

Comment: add those JS file in your head tag

Comment: I have done this already but it didn't do the work.

Comment: Why do you need to include theses scripts, each time you make the ajax call ?

Comment: Put those js files just after the </body> before ajax_loader_order() function. And having the code above, was there any error in the console?

Comment: these scripts contain styles and effects.

Comment: You don't need to add those js files under an ajax function because you can just put those at the end of the body and it will automatically render whatever code you have inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Add them after your ajax-script import in your html

Pseudocode:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="ajax.js" />
    <script src="js1.js" />
    <script src="js2.js" />
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

or:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="ajax.js" />
    <script src="js1.js" />
    <script src="js2.js" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this ajax script must be executed several times, it is for paging. So I have to include those js files each time.

Comment: yes it must be executed several times, but loaded only once